# Hide element from Parent component if children component returns null react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have requirement to hide element from parent component if children component returns null. I am rendering Accordion component, i would like to remove accordion panel from parent component if it doesn't contain any data without using `state`

//Parent component

const dataObj = {
bio: 'anthingdata',
}

```
const blocks = ['bio', 'address', 'payment'];
blocks.map(block => {
  const data = <Block block={block} />
  //if data exists or its length > 0 then render Component else null
  if(data) {
    <AccordionPanel={data} />
  }
})
```

//Block component

```
const Block = ({blockName})=> {
   //here i am checking if this property exists in dataObj then return it in div element
   let child = {}
   if(dataObj[blockName]) {
      child = <div>{dataObj[blockName]}</div>
   }

   return child;
}
```

Here `Block` component will return data for `bio` property and others will return `{}` so i don't want to render now other sections inside Parent component if Child component return `{}`